# How to detect undetected innerText change on DOM element with MutationObserver?

Tags: javascript, facebook, dom, google-chrome-extension, mutation-observers

I'm trying to write a browser extension that detects changes to the `innerText` of an HTML element on Facebook. For reasons I can't discern, when the *only* thing that changes on the target element is the innerText (or innerHTML), no mutation is observed.

However, if I write my own test program outside of Facebook, trying to detect an `innerText` change, it *does* create an observable DOM mutation. So first, here's an example of it working as expected ([fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/forgetcolor/8zyvuqes/4/)):

HTML:

```
<div id="trackmychanges">starting text</div>
<button id="button">press to trigger change on text above</button>
<div id="status"></div>
```

JS:

```
var target = document.getElementById('trackmychanges');

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    console.log(mutation.type);
    $('#status').text("got a "+mutation.type+" mutation!");
  });    
});

var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };

observer.observe(target, config);

$('#button').click(function() {
  $('#status').text("changing...");
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#trackmychanges').text("new text "+Math.random());
  }, 200);
})
```

But on Facebook this method doesn't work. The node whose innerText I'm trying to track there has the class name `UFILikeLink`. The following example code (paste into the Javascript console with Facebook running to test), sets up an `observer` as above.

Find the first "Like" button on the page (e.g. on the News Feed) and click it, or select a "reaction" (such as Wow, Love, Haha, etc.). Doing so will likely trigger a mutation as expected (because the first click on a "Like" also adds some attributes and children). However, if you use the reactions popup to select "Wow" and then use it again to select "Haha" or "Sad", then it doesn't work. In this case, because the only thing changing on the element is the `innerText`, nothing gets triggered. (Moving from Haha to Sad to Wow in any order has this effect because no attributes or children get modified in such a case---only the innerText). If you watch this node in the console's elements pane, you'll see the `innerText` change there, but still no mutation is observed.

```
var target = document.querySelector('.UFILikeLink');
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) { console.log(mutation.type); });    
});   
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };
observer.observe(target, config);
```

Is it possible to get notified of these `innerText` changes using a `MutationObserver`?

Comment: `.innerText` is not a jQuery method. Do you mean `.text()` when using jQuery? Or `.innerText = "value"` using `Node.innerText`?

Comment: Yes, thanks for that. I had the `.text()` in the line above. I removed the useless line from the code example.

Comment: Does substituting `.text()` for `.innerText()` return expected result?

Comment: The erroneous line wasn't affecting the output because I had above it a `.text()` line doing the same thing. So all I've done is clean up the working example code (which worked before and after). None of this changes the question or the puzzling lack of mutation on the second block of code as described.

Comment: What is the difference between the first example and the second example?

Comment: The second example is setup for pasting into the console on Facebook.com in order to illustrate the problem described. It uses the same method for detecting a mutation as the first example, but lacks the extra code to manipulate the HTML (relying solely on the console for output).

Comment: Facebook apparently replaces the entire element so the old one you observe is silently removed. Observe the first parent that is guaranteed to be unaltered (and you'll need subtree:true option).